# does uefi+legacy affect booting?

Tags: uefi

I have a uefi laptop.

I have the option to turn off uefi +legacy on the laptop and I have heard its good to turn it off while dual booting linux

So if I create bootable usb in uefi, will it boot in uefi+legacy?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would be required to Turn it ON back if you want to boot from a USB. Try it out. Also you can change the boot priority level towards the USB from the BIOS startup screen in that case it might run the USB. Most often keys used are F12 F11, F9 and F8.

Comment: it is currently off, if i create a bootable usb when its off, will it work when its on?